# .change() is not working because page is already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#location').change(function(){
    let selected_option = $(this).find(":selected").val();
     $('#locationHeading').text(selected_option)
  })
});
```

instead of waiting for a change on the #location which is a `<select>` I want to soon as the page loads do that function.

the reason being the selected option will already be selected once the page loads.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: `$('#location').change(function(){.........}).change();` .. Also can use `$(this).val();` instead of `$(this).find(":selected").val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.trigger()`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#location').change(function(){
    let selected_option = $(this).find(":selected").val();
     $('#locationHeading').text(selected_option)
  }).trigger('change') // <== add this
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="locationHeading"></h1>

<select id="location">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. so it's triggering the change function correct?

Answer (score 0):

Put the change handler in a separate function, and call it in addition to adding the listener:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    const loc = $('#location');
    const handler = () => {
        let selected_option = loc.find(":selected").val();
        $('#locationHeading').text(selected_option)
    };
    loc.on('change', handler);
    handler();
});
```